# Display subreport information in excel

Tags: acumatica

I have created a sub-report and embedded it in a report, the sub-report details appear when the report is run and also when the report is exported to PDF but when the report is exported to excel the sub-report details are not appearing, is possible for the information to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for sub- report details to appear in excel, the excel settings in the report designer should be 1,1. i.e the sub-report should be first item in its row.